# Python passing variable in function with [0]

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code, what does the [0] represent and what purpose does it serve?

```
print_xyz(abc_config.output_var("new_name", clustername, SP_PY_BASE)[0])
```

Comment: The function `output_var` returns some indexable element (e.g. list, tuple, something that implements `__getitem__`) and it is retrieving the first element. Simply print out `abc_config.output_var("new_name", clustername, SP_PY_BASE)` to see what the element being indexed is.

Comment: `[0]` means you are accessing the first element from the indexable object like list, tuple, set ...

Answer (score 1):

`abc_config.output_var("new_name", clustername, SP_PY_BASE)`

should be returning an array.
First element of this array is passed to print_xyz.

This could be equivalent to

```
my_list = abc_config.output_var("new_name", clustername, SP_PY_BASE)
print_xyz(my_list[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the `output_var()` method returns a list, and doing `[0]` gives it's first element.